# How to prove that a vector is Gaussian

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ be a Gaussian random variable, and let $Z_{n}$ be a sequence of random variables defined by $Z_{n}=a_{n}+b_{n}Y$.

How do I show that $Z_{n}$ is Gaussian?

Comment: In your title you talk about vectors; I don't see any?

Comment: let $H=<1,Y>$ so $Z_{n}$ will be a vector

Comment: This is elementary if you show that $Y$ is a Gaussian implies $bY$ and $a+Y$ are Gaussian for any constants $a,b$.

Comment: but i find a question that ask me to prove that !

Comment: AlexR. is correct; it suffices to show that $bY$ and $a+Y$ are Gaussian for a Gaussian random variable $Y$. So what do you know about Gaussian random variables (i.e. how can they be characterized)?